# failed to set property sslEnabledProtocols to TLSv1.2

Tags: ssl, openssl

WARNING [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule.begin Match [Server/Service/Connector/SSLHostConfig] failed to set property [sslEnabledProtocols] to [TLSv1.2]

Can we ignore this warning and can someone give solution for this?

I tried below steps:
Step one: Convert the x.509 cert and key to a pkcs12 file
Step two: Convert the pkcs12 file to a Java keystore

Comment: (0) this is not about programming or development and thus offtopic, but (1) there is no sslEnabledProtocols attribute in SSLHostConfig for tomcat; the sslEnabledProtocols attribute in old versions of _Connector_ is replaced by simply 'protocols' in SSLHostConfig in 8.5 up (2) limiting to TLSv1.2 is a bad idea and will get worse in future (3) since approximately 2015 Java has been able to read PKCS12 files by default and doesn't need conversion to JKS, and anyway this issue has nothing to do with the keystore